# Cant add table to data model EF6

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have a data model and later I added 2 new tables.  Both of these new tables have primary keys defined and the two tables also have relations.  When I go to update the data model and add these two new tables, they are not listed.  Im tempted to delete the model and recreate, but surely there is a better way.  Im using VS 2012 (update 4) and EF6

Comment: Close VS and open again. Sometimes work

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I was still pointing at an old database.  My data model is in a class library and that project has its own app config which was pointed to the old database.  Once I fixed that, bingo the new tables showed up.  Glad it was so easy.